# Preventing data-ajax attributes from executing

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this link (also [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/225pW/)):

```
<a class="update noClick" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#vote11" href="/Tutors/RateNegative/11" onclick="return window.confirm('Are you sure?');">qwer</a>
```

Now what I want it to do, is, after user clicks on it, I want it to display confirmation window (it does that), but I want to prevent ajax to do anything unless user accepts confirmation window. Currently, if user denies this window, ajax is making the request anyways.

How can I do that?

Comment: Where is the AJAX code? `data-ajax` attributes don't execute anything.

Comment: If user clicks "Cancel" - action is canceled, nothing happens

Comment: @Barmar: They don't? Then why does this work? O.o I rendered it through asp.net mvc's framework, so it seems that there must be something else that is executing it...

Comment: If you're using a framework that automates things like this, you should mention it in the question, and add the framework's tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YddmF/

I just moved the ajax to a separate, hidden anchor, and click it with javascript if the user confirms.

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.checkUser();">qwer</a>

<a id="ajax-anchor" class="update" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#vote11" href="/Tutors/RateNegative/11"></a>
```

JS

```
window.checkUser = function () {
  if (window.confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        document.getElementById("ajax-anchor").click();
    }
}
```

CSS

```
#ajax-anchor { display: none; }
```

Comment: That is pretty smart, i like it, thanks. ;) But I already found a solution that is less hacky. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was pretty simple. Instead of using `onclick` attribute, I needed to add `data-ajax-begin` attribute, and put my code in there. If `begin` returns false, then nothing happens.